# javascript array filled strangely

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, angularjs

I am writing an app in angular, and creating an array of custom services called Workbooks that each have an array of custom services called Views. I fill the array with a simple for loop, but for some reason this is producing unexpected results:

After the first iteration, there is one workbook in the array:
`Workbook 1`

After the second, two workbooks **titled workbook 2**: `Workbook 2` `Workbook 2`

After the third: `Workbook 3` `Workbook 3` `Workbook 3`

And so on. How could this be happening? Here is a simplified version of the code that creates the workbooks and adds them to the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var workbook = Workbook;
    workbook.setTitle("workbook " + (i + 1));
    for (var j = 0; j <2; j++ ) {
        var view = View;
        view.setTitle("view " + (j + 1));
        workbook.addView(view);
    }

    workbooks[i] = workbook;

    //this next for loop can be used to print the array as described    
    for (var k = 0; k < workbooks.length; k++) {
        console.log(workbooks[k].getTitle());
    }
}

return workbooks;
```

How could this happen? The ith workbook is assigned a title and then assigned to  the ith spot in the array. When `i` is 2, how can a workbook called `Workbook 3` be assigned to the 0th and 1st spot in the array as well as the 2nd?

For reference, here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L4bh0RSus6ZgKlUgwtvF) to the relevant code from the app. Thanks!

Comment: They're all the same object, perhaps you're missing a `new` at `var workbook = Workbook;`?

Comment: or an `Object.create(Workbook)` if `Workbook` is an Object which it kind of looks like it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return new object per factory call in your implementation of factory.

```
GATapp.factory('Workbook', function () { 
    return function () {
        var title;
        var views = [];
        this.getTitle = function () {
            return title;
        }
        this.setTitle = function (newTitle) {
            title = newTitle;
        }
        this.getViews = function () {
            return views;
        }
        this.addView = function (newView) {
            views.push(newView);
        }
        this.getView = function (i) {
            return views[i].getTitle();
        }
    };
});
```

And create new object when you consume the factory.

```
var workbook = new Workbook();
```

Please take a look. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cyCa5V?p=preview)

Comment: Oh you're right, I needed to return an object in my factory. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the ith workbook to every spot in the array, you are assigning the SAME workbook to each of them, and then updating the title.  You need to make

```
var workbook = Workbook;
```

into this

```
var workbook = new Workbook;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
var workbook = Workbook;
workbook.setTitle("workbook " + (i + 1));
```

Each time through this loop, you are re-creating the variable 'workbook', and assigning it the name 'workbook X'.

But it is looking like you aren't creating a NEW workbook each time, instead you are reusing the same reference, so each workbook ends up being simply a reference to the same object.

When you step through the loop the next time, you are simply reassigning the title of this reference, and both of them are updating.

Try this and see how it responds.

```
var workbook; // Just cleaner, avoids re-declaring the variable
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    workbook = new Workbook; // avoids re-referencing the same Workbook
    workbook.setTitle("workbook " + (i + 1));
    for (var j = 0; j <2; j++ ) {
        var view = View;
        view.setTitle("view " + (j + 1));
        workbook.addView(view);
    }

    workbooks[i] = workbook;

    //this next for loop can be used to print the array as described    
    for (var k = 0; k < workbooks.length; k++) {
        console.log(workbooks[k].getTitle());
    }
}

return workbooks;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with my code! I didn't realize I was continually referencing the same object. :)

Comment: Not a problem... javascript gets kinda strange in some spots.  It is an extremely flexible and powerful language, but don't let the syntax fool you; there are a LOT of places buried deeply under the hood that JavaScript does not think or act like a standard C style language.  I might strongly recommend the book "JavaScript: the Good Parts"... it helps you understand the way JavaScript 'thinks' about objects.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out! I have been trying to find a good book to get the big picture on JavaScript like that.